# Elasticsearch Ingest-Attachment Plugin - Where to get zip distribution

Tags: repository, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm looking for a way to install the **ingest-attachment** plugin in offline mode.
So to do it i **first need download the zip distribution** of this plugin.

Official documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/ingest-attachment.html) provides a non working link on their artifact repository

Would anyone have an idea where to download a stable/released zip version of this plugin ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please if you think question is stupid, add a comment instead of downvoting it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok seems like the link they propose is broken cause the version does not exist anymore in their artifact repository.

I had to get a previous version (5.1.1) instead. It's just a shame they do not track any dead link in their documentation for massive indexation / analytics products company... or at least propose a clear URL to browse all available versions.